# How to abort if command fails in Unix shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, gulp

I'm not very great with shell scripting and still couldn't find a solution to this. I want to run a command `gulp tslint` and if it returns errors, abort the script.

So far I tried `gulp tslint || exit 1` with no success. I think it somehow is  returning true, even though it has errors when i run it on command prompt e.g.

```
[12:30:14] Starting 'tslint'...
[12:30:14] Finished 'tslint' after 9.49 ms
[12:30:16] [gulp-tslint] error (quotemark) payment-types.ts[18, 53]: " should be '
```

How can i make it work?

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gulp returns 0 when tasks fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688613/gulp-returns-0-when-tasks-fail)

Comment: as gulps returns 0 when error occures it has no sense to analyze returned code, but you still can parse command output manually, and if you find an error - go to exit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a gulp question, rather than a shell question. As gulp completes successfully (i.e. reaches an exit without raising an error), it doesn't tell the shell that anything is wrong. The best way to address this is to reconfigure gulp to interpret lint failures as errors.

Could you post your `gulpfile.js`? Specifically your `tslint` task.

It probably looks like

```
gulp.task('tslint', function() {
    gulp.src("**/*.ts")
        .pipe(tslint.report('prose'))
});
```

You can instruct your reporter to fail on error by changing this to:

```
gulp.task('tslint', function() {
    gulp.src("**/*.ts")
        .pipe(tslint.report('prose', {emitError: true}))
});
```

edit: look at the gulp-tslint [README](https://github.com/panuhorsmalahti/gulp-tslint) for more details on emitError