# How to stop npm start , when lint or Unit testcase fails?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using npm start with lint and unit test case, if lint or test case fails, npm should not up the api, but I am not able to do.

Here is code I am using:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "gulp lint & npm test & node src/server/index.js",
    "test": "mocha --timeout 10000"
  },
```

Please help me what I have to do for it, I searched on internet also, but not getting the proper solution.

Comment: are you on windows or unix based env?

Comment: window based env.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply rewrite the code like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "gulp lint && npm test && node src/server/index.js",
  "test": "mocha --timeout 10000"
},
```

Double && will never start execution of node server if previous steps contains errors.

Answer (score 2):

Use `&&` instead of `&`:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "gulp lint && npm test && node src/server/index.js",
"test": "mocha --timeout 10000"
```

},

Comment: But if lint fail it is not stop, it run the test case, but if I removed gulp lint and error in test case it is stopping...Is something I need to set in grunt file to return false?

Comment: Apparently, this is how gulp work. I'm not a big expert in gulp. Try to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688613/gulp-returns-0-when-tasks-fail and this https://github.com/sindresorhus/jshint-stylish/issues/6